How should I pray in the afternoon and evening as a Noahide?
I know how to pray in the morning but I haven't really found anything about evening and afternoon. Since I don't have much money, I didn't want to come across a book explaining prayers for us because I was afraid it might not be in there. In the Noahide books I have, there is mostly history written but prayer is not really mentioned. Now I pray every morning as I found in a Noahide website but in the afternoon I do a prayer to the Lord so that every sick, healthy, strong, old save the day and in the evening I pray to the Lord to thank them for giving me a chance, ask for his servants to help and forgive us and swear that I will remain faithful to the 7 commandments. However, is any prayer recommended, that's what I want to know.

There is no obligation for a Noahide to pray at all. A Noahide certainly cannot properly pray from a siddur, which is written with a Jewish worshipper in mind. How can you possibly recite the words “who has sanctified us with his mitzvot and commanded us”, or “God of our forefathers Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob”, or “from Egypt you redeemed us”?

take a look at https://noahideworldcenter.org/products/english-bsh-test

Great question! Most of us (like most Jews) are woefully unschooled on Noahide responsibilities beyond the 7 mistvot. Your best bet would likely be to reach out to a local Chabad rabbi as they are they have made supporting Bnei Noach a central part of their movement to a much greater extent than anyone else in Judaism
